# Функция TestRestTemplate.withBasicAuth() не работает

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-security

Функция TestRestTemplate.withBasicAuth() не работает
В настройках доступ ко всем ендпоинтам открыт. 
Переопределенная функция Spring Security loadUserByUsername() не срабатывает при вызове функции withBasicAuth(), хотя в конфиге UserDetailsServiceImpl я указывал её. Когда я пытаюсь получить текущего пользователя после withBasicAuth()

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().GetAuthentication().GetPrincipal().GetUsername()
```

я получаю anonUser.

```
// security config
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().and()
            .anonymous().and()
            .servletApi().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("j_email")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll();

    http.logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}

// code on server
// get user from db
private CUser getDBUser() {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username;

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        username = principal.toString();
    }

    System.out.println(username);
    CUser dbCUser = userService.findByEmail(username);

    return dbCUser;
}

// endpoint /cabinet/spring_test, login test
@GetMapping("/spring_test")
public ResponseEntity<Message> onSpringTest() {
    if (getDBUser() != null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Message("/spring_test", "test success"), HttpStatus.OK);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            new Message("/spring_test",
                    "Unauthorized."),
            HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}

// unit test on login
@Test
public void testLogin() {
    CUser user = new CUser(
            "vex788",
            passwordEncoder.encode("testvex"),
            UserRole.ADMIN,
            "testvex@mail.com",
            "0123456789",
            false,
            "123.45.67.89"
    );

    if (userService.addUser(user)) System.out.println("Admin added.");

    TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Message> result = restTemplate
            .withBasicAuth("testvex@mail.com", "testvex")
            .getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/cabinet/spring_test", Message.class);
    System.out.println(result.getBody().getMessage());
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, result.getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: попрбуйте без passwordEncoder

Comment: Пробовал. Сохранял в бд без шифрования, и отсылал шифрованный пароль. Не работает. В конфиге я указываю bcryptPasswordEncoder, и соответственно использую его при шифровании.